# C:/Program is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows

I have JAVA_HOME variable in System variables and is set to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

I get an error when I try to use command `%JAVA_HOME%`

> C:/Program is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I understand it is because of space in the path after Program,

I have also tried using quotes across the path but it did not resolve the issue.

i.e

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"
```

but no help.

Edit: I tried removing ones with Program Files at all.

Now my System path variable looks like this:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

Environment path variable looks like this:

```
 C:\Users\dev4\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\mongodb\bin;
```

So, I do not really see any of these with space or program files in path
and yet when I try

%Path%

it gives the same error.

EDIT 2:

cd %PATH% gives The file name or extension is too long.

however cd %JAVA_HOME% works

Edit 3: Now, the PATH variable has location fo JDK bin but none of my java commands are recognized

Comment: Show how you used quotes. It will resolve the problem.

Comment: Updated. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: %JAVA_HOME% is not a command.  It will try to interpret as one, all it can come up with is "C:\Program" as a possible command.  It isn't.  Type an actual command, like CD %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: Thaanks . It worked. but I have JDK installed and it has jarsigner in its bin yet my command does not work. Could you please point out the possibilities? It says command not found

Comment: Infact any of the java commands. javac didi not work either

Comment: Typing `%Path%` on the command line will interpret the content of `path` as a command.  Use `echo %Path%`, `set path` or just `path`. The latter is specific to `%Path%`, the others apply to any environment variable.

Comment: The title and error message show `C:/` not `C:\ ` as required. Which is it?

Comment: Please check the update. Do I need to set classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrapping the variables in double quotes should work

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
```

Or if you host supports it use a short name

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

Comment: What happens with "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"?

Answer (score 0):

For all general case use the short folder path.

the short form folder name can be obtained by executing `cmd prompt` and visiting the parent directory and type `dir /x` and press enter you will see the short form of sub folder names

ex:- `C:/Progra~1/MARIAD~1.2/bin/mysql.exe` in the place of

```
C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.2/bin/mysql.exe
```

here short form of MariaDB 10.2 can be obtained form visiting c:/program files/ in cmd prompt and type dir /x